# Extacting tar.gz source code downloaded with wget yocto in specified directory

Tags: kernel, yocto

I want in my yocto bb file an option to extract a tar.gz in specified folder like destsuffix when we use git.

I have tried the following syntaxes but it does not working :

```
SRC_URI += "http://nwl.cc/pub/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux-1.9.tar.gz;name=cryptodev;subpath=${S}/drivers/cryptodev"
```

and I have tried with destsuffix and it does not work also:

```
SRC_URI += "http://nwl.cc/pub/cryptodev-linux/cryptodev-linux-1.9.tar.gz;name=cryptodev;destsuffix=${S}/drivers/cryptodev"
```

How can I can extract source code in specified directory ?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the unpack documentation [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#bb-the-unpack), you have to use **subdir** instead.

I created a simple recipe for this to test it and it worked fine:

```
SUMMARY = "Example recipe to unpack to custom distination"
LICENSE = "MIT"
SRC_URI = "file://file1.tar.xz;subdir=${S}/dir1/dir2/dir3/"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
```

Take note that dir1/dir2/dir3 do not exist in my working directory, so Yoto created them and extracted file1 to **${S}/dir1/dir2/dir3**.